# MySQL: почему не работает while или любой другой цикл

Tags: while, циклы, mysql

Решил вот с MSSQL по чуть-чуть изучать MySQL и наткнулся сразу на проблему...

Вопрос: почему это не работает?

```
SET @counter = 1;
WHILE (@counter < 20) DO
    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END WHILE;
```

Версия SQL такая: mysql-installer-community-5.6.11.0.

Компилил это дело в Eclipse, а так же в консоли с использованием: `delimiter //`

Сколько не гуглил, сколько разных вариантов других циклов не пробовал, всё бестолку, говорит синтаксическая ошибка.

---

вот это:

```
SET @counter = @counter + 1;
```

и вот это:

```
SET @counter = 1;
```

Компилит по отдельности нормально, а вот с While-ом никак...=(

---

Begin после do уже пытался ставить. Так же пытался перед While ставить название с двоеточием и потом закрывать это дело в END. Никак не работает. REPEAT тоже не работает...

---

В процедуре кстати тоже не работает:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mypro ()
BEGIN
SET @counter = 1;
WHILE (@counter < 20) DO
    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END WHILE;
END
```

---

Где я туплю?

Comment: Замените 

    SET @counter = 1;

на 

    SET @counter := 1;

Comment: А в чём разница?
Что так:

SET @counter = 1;

Что так:

SET @counter := 1;

Одинаково ведь работает.

While по прежнему не работает.

Comment: А почему у меня работает? Где я допустил ошибку?

     show create procedure mypro;
     ...
     | mypro     |          | CREATE DEFINER=`alex`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `mypro`()
     BEGIN
     SET @counter := 1;
     WHILE (@counter < 20) DO
       SET @counter := @counter + 1;
     END WHILE;
     END | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      | utf8_general_ci    |
     ...
     select @counter;
     +----------+
     | @counter |
     +----------+
     |       20 |
     +----------+
     1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: А почему у тебя работает? У меня не работает...

Такс, ща буду другие версии MySQL пробовать, мб проблема в том что у мня она кривая...

Comment: У меня Server version: 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu). А как оно не работает?

Comment: Вот так в консоли:

DELIMITER // 

CREATE PROCEDURE mypro () 
BEGIN 
SET @counter = 1; 
WHILE (@counter < 20) DO 
SET @counter = @counter + 1; 
END WHILE; 
END // 


Error Code : 1064 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE (@counter < 20) DO SET @counter = @counter + 1 ' at line 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While только внутри begin end  работает. А вообще этот код работает точно:

```
create procedure procedure1() 
begin
set @p := 2;
while @p<20 do set @p:=@p+1; end while;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

По сути ответ сверху (@vkovalchuk88) исчерпывающий, все логические операторы, такие как (if statement, switch case, while do, loop ...)
работают в нутри функции или процедуры, посмотри, как писать функции и процедуры в sql, там по идее работает все, кроме foreach, его решения я не нашел, написано что он внедрен в мускл с 2011, но мои mySQL его не видет.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_sqlserver.asp

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql

https://www.w3resource.com/sql/sql-procedure.php

единственно вроде функция возвращает результат, а процедура вроде нет, это учти.

---

касательно твоей процедуры, нехватает делимитра, и знака "//", в начале и в конце, как описано в коде.
**CONCAT()** и **@result**, только для того, что бы продемонстрировать его работу.

```
DELIMITER // -- is imporant
    CREATE PROCEDURE mypro ()
    BEGIN
    SET @counter = 1;
    SET @result = "";
    WHILE (@counter < 20) DO
        SET @counter = @counter + 1;
        SET @result = CONCAT(@result, ", ", @counter);
    END WHILE;
    SELECT @result;
END // -- end need be with "//"
```

сейчас работает

Comment: После того, как вы ответили, возможно ответ сверху стал снизу. Какой ответ вы упомянули? Добавте в ответе, например - ответ от  @user123456.

Comment: Спасибо, я указал уже.

Comment: я уже задавал этот вопрос на английском, если надо, вот [сылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363057/if-statement-in-mysql-insert-is-not-working)