# Почему в MySQL (MariaDB) цикл не работает даже в процедуре?

Tags: mysql, sql, циклы, phpmyadmin, mariadb

**2 UPDATE:** Есть над чем подумать:

```
delimiter ;;
drop procedure if exists test2;;
create procedure test2()
begin
select ‘Hello World’;
end
;;
```

---

**UPDATE:** Код (от [@Igor Dyshlenko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/345120/igor-dyshlenko)):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure1;
DELIMITER //
create procedure procedure1() 
begin
set @p := 2;
while @p<20 do set @p:=@p+1; end while;
end;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Тоже не работает:

> Ошибка
>
> Вероятно, SQL-запрос содержит ошибку. При наличии таковой, ниже будет
>   выведена ошибка MySQL-сервера, облегчающая диагностику проблемы.
>
> ERROR: Неизвестная пунктуация @ 99 STR: // SQL: DROP PROCEDURE IF
>   EXISTS procedure1;# MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк).
>   DELIMITER // create procedure procedure1()  begin set @p := 2; while
>   @p<20 do set @p:=@p+1; end while; end;//
>
> ## MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк). DELIMITER ;
>
> SQL запрос:
>
> DELIMITER ;
>
> Ответ MySQL:
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

---

И так, согласно [MySQL: почему не работает while или любой другой цикл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/269312/mysql-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-while-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb) цикл в **MySQL** работает, и достаточно написать такой запрос для проверки и всё получится:

```
create procedure procedure1() 
begin
set @p := 2;
while @p<20 do set @p:=@p+1; end while;
end;
```

*Код от [@vkovalchuk88](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/13851/vkovalchuk88)*

НО! Я проверяю этот код в **phpMyAdmin**, с характеристиками:

```
Сервер: MySQL (Localhost via UNIX socket)
Тип сервера: MariaDB
Версия сервера: 5.5.60-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server
Версия протокола: 10
```

И получаю:

> Ошибка
>
> SQL запрос:
>
> create procedure procedure1()  begin set @p := 2;
>
> Ответ MySQL:
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '' at line 3

[image: лог]

[100% масштаб](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGYGd.png)

Так всё же, как использовать цикл?

**Example** из документации (https://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/loops/while.php) тоже не работает...

**P.S.** Я постарался предоставить полную информацию о моих действиях, и о том, что я знаю (**я только начинаю разбираться с запросами к БД**). Поисковые запросы по этому вопросу не дают нормальных ответов, я привёл пример с сайта ru.stackoverflow.com, чтобы показать, что и где у меня не получается... Прошу модераторов, и пользователей помочь в этом вопросе, а не давать тег **duplicate** и ставить **downvote**. Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Сервер Вам отвечает абсолютно правильно. Потому что для того, чтобы создать сторед процедуру (функцию, триггер), нужно сначала сменить разделитель для интертрепатора SQL, чтобы он, встретив `;`, не кинулся сразу же пытаться выполнить выражение. Кстати, это есть и в примере по приведенной Вами ссылке на документацию. Т.е. сначала меняем разделитель, и интертрепатор перестает реагировать на `;`:

```sql
DELIMITER //
```

Затем создаем процедуру:

```sql
create procedure procedure1() 
begin
set @p := 2;
while @p<20 do set @p:=@p+1; end while;
end;//
```

Обратите внимание на то, что оператор завершается символами `//` - нашим новым разделителем. Только в этом месте интертрепатор командной строки mysql начинает обрабатывать все, что введено ранее, как единый оператор. Теперь надо возвернуть взад стандартный разделитель, чтобы Вы комфортно могли работать, а интертрепатор mysql - не сбивался при выполнении процедур:

```sql
DELIMITER ;
```

Статья, на которую Вы ссылаетесь как на источник, по всей видимости, рассчитана на **более подготовленного** читателя, который о необходимости смены разделителя знает.

Comment: Вот такой результат по Вашему коду:
`Вероятно, SQL-запрос содержит ошибку. При наличии таковой, ниже будет выведена ошибка MySQL-сервера, облегчающая диагностику проблемы.

ERROR: Неизвестная пунктуация @ 95
STR: //
SQL: create procedure procedure1() 
begin
set @p := 2;
while @p<20 do set @p:=@p+1; end while;
end;//`

Comment: `MariaDB [teleteka_metadata]> DELIMITER //` 
`MariaDB [teleteka_metadata]> create procedure procedure1()` 
`    -> begin` 
`    -> set @p := 2;` 
`    -> while @p<20 do set @p:=@p+1; end while;` 
`    -> end;//` 
`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.015 sec)` 
`MariaDB [teleteka_metadata]> DELIMITER ;` 
`MariaDB [teleteka_metadata]> call procedure1();` 
`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.004 sec)`

Comment: Откуда у Вас символ ->? Это phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Это консоль. Она так обозначает перевод на следующую строку.

Comment: А в phpMyAdmin код работает?

Comment: Дано задание, нужно сделать используя цикл, преподаватель проверяет правильность в phpMyAdmin, во вкладке SQL

Comment: Вы вначале и в конце добавили соответствующие строки `DELIMITER //` и `DELIMITER ;`?

Comment: Я же показал код новый в начале вопроса - UPDATE, там есть новые ошибки. Одна была что функция уже существует о_О, я уже и DROP добавил, но результата нет.

Comment: В общем, как я понимаю, создать цикл - это нереально... Я уже 20 раз пробовал разные ответы, и всё мимо.

Comment: Проблема у Вас не с циклом. У Вас сторед процедура не создается. Я с phpmyadmin'ом давненько последний раз работал, гляньте вкладки "триггеры" и "операции". https://medium.com/@nishitvmaheta/create-stored-procedures-in-php-myadmin-ccf02c323a7e

Comment: Операции - там создание / переименование БД. Триггеры мы не проходили, да и выполнять будут в SQL. Мне это давно решить можно было бы, отправив запросы через php, и на нём сделав цикл, обработав там всё, но нужен SQL...

Comment: Ну вот, значит с SQL не получится. Процедуры ещё не давали, я не знаю как выкручиваться :/

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь. Я хотел поставить +1 Вашему ответу, но пока не могу - правила stackoverflow не позволяют этого... Принять ответ не могу, из-за задания, не сочтите за моё хамство :( Мне нужно будет что-то придумать, если не получится, то даже не знаю, как быть. Может искать альтернативу циклам придётся.

Comment: Мне кажется, у Вас какая-то то ли древняя, то ли обрезанная версия phpmyadmin. Код, который Вы привели, - гарантированно рабочий: `MariaDB [teleteka_metadata]> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procedure1;` 
`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.004 sec)` 
`MariaDB [teleteka_metadata]> DELIMITER //` 
`MariaDB [teleteka_metadata]> create procedure procedure1() ` 
`    -> begin`
`    -> set @p := 2;`
`    -> while @p<20 do set @p:=@p+1; end while;`
`    -> end;//`
`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.002 sec)`
`MariaDB [teleteka_metadata]> DELIMITER ;`
`MariaDB [teleteka_metadata]>`

Comment: Характеристики БД, и всего, что с ней связано, я привёл в самом тексте вопроса. Мне кажется, это не версия, это невозможность использовать циклы во вкладке SQL...

Comment: Попробуйте во вкладке SQL создать в принципе сторед- процедуру без while - оставьте в теле функции одну строку `set @p := 2;` - получится ли создать процедуру в принципе?

Comment: Я кажется нашёл решение...

Comment: 2 UPDATE в тексте вопроса написал код, который SQL пропускает. Единственное, сделал внутри SELECT * FROM ... и результат 0 строк

Comment: Да ладно, я справился? call test2;; и всё? Это слишком просто... М-да интересно, это ещё кто-то решит? Спасибо @Igor Dyshlenko, Вы меня сильно промотивировали, про **DELIMITER** Вы верно говорили, он нужен, но работать будет только "DELIMITER ;;", а не "DELIMITER //" Во всяком случае у меня так, и да, ещё: call, то есть вызов нужно не забыть...